Side Bar loading failure in bootstrap blazor
I am trying to create an application using Blazor. In that application I am using sidebar component of Blazor. I have installed Blazor bootstrap and have given every reference of dependencies which are mentioned in the site https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/sidebar, yet the side bar is showing loading three dots icon in it. Attaching all the files and codes here.
MainLayout.razor 

@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="bb-page">

    <Sidebar @ref="sidebar"
             Href="/"
             CustomIconName="bi bi-apple"
             Title="Blazor Bootstrap"
             BadgeText="v1.3.1"
             DataProvider="SidebarDataProvider" />

    <main>
        <div class="bb-top-row px-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
            <Icon Name="IconName.List" role="button" @onclick="ToggleSidebar" />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            <div class="py-2">Page content goes here</div>
        </article>
    </main>

</div>

@code {
    Sidebar sidebar = default!;
    IEnumerable<NavItem>? navItems;

    private async Task<SidebarDataProviderResult> SidebarDataProvider(SidebarDataProviderRequest request)
    {
        if (navItems is null)
            navItems = GetNavItems();

        return await Task.FromResult(request.ApplyTo(navItems));
    }

    private IEnumerable<NavItem> GetNavItems()
    {
        navItems = new List<NavItem>
        {
            new NavItem { Id = "1", Href = "/getting-started", IconName = IconName.HouseDoorFill, Text = "Getting Started"},

            new NavItem { Id = "2", IconName = IconName.LayoutSidebarInset, Text = "Content", IconColor = IconColor.Primary },
            new NavItem { Id = "3", Href = "/icons", IconName = IconName.PersonSquare, Text = "Icons", ParentId="2"},

            new NavItem { Id = "4", IconName = IconName.ExclamationTriangleFill, Text = "Components", IconColor = IconColor.Success },
            new NavItem { Id = "5", Href = "/alerts", IconName = IconName.CheckCircleFill, Text = "Alerts", ParentId="4"},
            new NavItem { Id = "6", Href = "/breadcrumb", IconName = IconName.SegmentedNav, Text = "Breadcrumb", ParentId="4"},
            new NavItem { Id = "7", Href = "/sidebar", IconName = IconName.LayoutSidebarInset, Text = "Sidebar", ParentId="4"},

            new NavItem { Id = "8", IconName = IconName.WindowPlus, Text = "Forms", IconColor = IconColor.Danger },
            new NavItem { Id = "9", Href = "/autocomplete", IconName = IconName.InputCursorText, Text = "Auto Complete", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "10", Href = "/currency-input", IconName = IconName.CurrencyDollar, Text = "Currency Input", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "11", Href = "/number-input", IconName = IconName.InputCursor, Text = "Number Input", ParentId="8"},
            new NavItem { Id = "12", Href = "/switch", IconName = IconName.ToggleOn, Text = "Switch", ParentId="8"},
        };

        return navItems;
    }

    private void ToggleSidebar() => sidebar.ToggleSidebar();
}


_Import.razor

@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Sample_Forecast
@using Sample_Forecast.Components
@using BlazorBootstrap;


app.razor

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sample_Forecast.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.0.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-gQhCDsnnnUfaRzD8k1L5llCCV6O9HN09zClIzzeJ8OJ9MpGmIlCxm+pdCkqTwqJ4JcjbojFr79rl2F1mzcoLMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.Bootstrap/blazor.bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

Program.cs

using Sample_Forecast.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddBlazorBootstrap();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

I followed steps mentioned in https://demos.blazorbootstrap.com/sidebar site

You missed the render mode, please add the code in your App.razor.
<head>
    ...
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    ...
</body>


